# wlst command's output lost after redirect/stopredirect

Tags: weblogic, wlst

my wlst script:

```
redirect('/dev/null', 'false')
connect('name','pswd','t3://host:port')
stopRedirect()
state('AdminServer', 'Server')
```

As you can see, I want to hide output of `connect` command, and show output of `state` command. But after running above script, I did't see output of `state`.

What's wrong with my script ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an issue with the redirect command, once you have specified:

```
redirect('/dev/null', 'false')
```

The false turns off everything from stdout... and it doesn't come back when you issue `stopRedirect`. An easy work around is to do the following:

```
redirect('/dev/null', 'false')
connect('name','pswd','t3://host:port')
stopRedirect()
redirect('/dev/null', 'true')
state('AdminServer', 'Server')
```

Effectively turning stdout back on.

I also found [this blog](http://www.javamonamour.org/2011/08/wlst-redirecting-all-output-to-file.html) talking about the same problem.